# Node.js socket.io IPv6 supported?

Tags: node.js

I've been developing a node.js application for quite a while on my home system my computer name/host name is 'big-mumma', IP address is 192.168.1.91.

My node application listens on port 8000, when testing on my local development system I can connect to using Firefox to:

http://localhost:8000 or http://192.168.1.91:8000/ or http://big-mumma:8000/

The site is displayed and I am presented with a login dialog, once I login the application uses socket.io to send the details to the node app and authenticate, it then allows me access to the rest of the application.

On the actual target system I cannot connect using the host name of the system, the localhost, IP and host name work for accessing the site but I cannot get past the login dialog when using the host name.

http://localhost:8000, http://192.168.16.123:8000 works completely but http://timesheet_demo:8000/ which translates to the IPv4 192.168.16.123 doesn't work properly.

I know this isn't a lot to go on and I would be more than happy to supply further information.  The only difference between my system 'big-mumma' and the target system is that the target system is running in a virtual machine Windows Server 2012, where as my system is Windows 7.

The strange thing is that if I check the database running on either system the audit log I've created and maintain shows a valid login for all addresses.

Comment: what's the public ip of the target system?

Comment: There isn't one its on a private LAN.

Comment: You write "I cannot connect using ..., but I cannot get passed the login dialog". So you get the login dialog, but cannot log in?

Comment: Ok, sorry, maybe I wasn't very clear.  Using all addresses the application delivers the login page and allows me to login as far as writing the audit entry into the database, but what it should do after this is relocate using: response.writeHead(302, objRelocator); this works for all except the entry which uses the domain name on the system running the virtual machine.

Comment: It seems that on the virtual machine cookies are not being created, I can see on my local system that cookies are created ok.  This only happens on the virtual machine when using the domain name, when using local host or the IP everything is ok.

Comment: Is IPv6 supported with socket.io?  I've seen quite a lot of posts on Google that suggest it isn't.